# Why italic font does not work in my Vim color scheme?

Tags: vim

I created my own color scheme in Vim, and I am trying to make the comments in italic. I used the following line:

```
highlight Comment cterm=italic
```

But it didn't work everywhere. To be more specific, I am working on a remote cluster and on my personal laptop. In my laptop this works perfectly, but in the cluster this does not work. Instead, Vim higlights the comments...

I also tried to use gui=italic and term=italic as well, still it does not work.

Reading in this site I found that this is most of the time due to the type of terminal. Still, the terminal on the cluster is xterm-256color and it is the same exact kind of terminal that I am using on my local laptop.
I also tried to see if the cluster terminal supports the italic font, through:

```
echo -e "\e[3m foo \e[23m"
```

And I can see the text in italic.
So, what is that I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It’s possible that the terminfo on the remote cluster does not set the start italic and stop italic escape sequences.